# TensorFlow Dataset Shuffle Each Epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [manual](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data) on the Dataset class in Tensorflow, it shows how to shuffle the data and how to batch it. However, it's not apparent how one can shuffle the data *each epoch*. I've tried the below, but the data is given in exactly the same order the second epoch as in the first. Does anybody know how to shuffle between epochs using a Dataset?

```
n_epochs = 2
batch_size = 3

data = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(12)

data = data.repeat(n_epochs)
data = data.batch(batch_size)
next_batch = data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))

print("new epoch")
data = data.shuffle(12)
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My environment: Python 3.6, TensorFlow 1.4.

TensorFlow has added `Dataset` into `tf.data`.

You should be cautious with the position of `data.shuffle`. In your code, the epochs of data has been put into the `dataset`'s buffer before your `shuffle`. Here is two usable examples to shuffle dataset.

**shuffle all elements**

```
# shuffle all elements
import tensorflow as tf

n_epochs = 2
batch_size = 3
buffer_size = 5

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
print("epoch 1")
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
print("epoch 2")
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
```

OUTPUT:

```
epoch 1
[1 4 5]
[3 0 7]
[6 9 8]
[10  2 11]
epoch 2
[2 0 6]
[1 7 4]
[5 3 8]
[11  9 10]
```

**shuffle between batches, not shuffle in a batch**

```
# shuffle between batches, not shuffle in a batch
import tensorflow as tf

n_epochs = 2
batch_size = 3
buffer_size = 5

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
print("epoch 1")
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
print("epoch 2")
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
```

OUTPUT:

```
epoch 1
[0 1 2]
[6 7 8]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
epoch 2
[3 4 5]
[0 1 2]
[ 9 10 11]
[ 9 10 11]
```

Comment: By shuffling between batches you mean batch order is to be shuffled and not the elements inside the batch?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you are using the same `next_batch` for both cases. So, depedening on what you really want, you may need to recreate `next_batch` before your second call to `sess.run` such as shown below, otherwise the `data = data.shuffle(12)` does not have any effect on the `next_batch` you created earlier in the code.

```
n_epochs = 2
batch_size = 3

data = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(12)

data = data.repeat(n_epochs)
data = data.batch(batch_size)
next_batch = data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))

print("new epoch")
data = data.shuffle(12)

"""See how I recreate next_batch after the data has been shuffled"""
next_batch = data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
for _ in range(4):
    print(sess.run(next_batch))
```

Please, let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: How would you couple this with the definition of a graph that you use this data with? It seems to me from your solution that you would have to re-define the graph everytime you re-create the dataset because the variables returned by `get_next()` will be used as inputs to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution that does not need to call `repeat`:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(12)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset.cardinality(), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
```